# gradle fails to compile app:dexDebug

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

When I compile I get an error about dexDebug that I can not solve.  I am using the JSON-simple library, the jReddit library and the Apache Commons library.  I have never seen this error before and have no idea how to fix it.  Thanks in advance!

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.techredesign.uiforreddit"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile group: 'com.github.jreddit', name: 'jreddit', version: '1.0.3'
    compile "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1"
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'



}
```

and here is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try running your build with --info or --debug params to have more info regarding the failure.

Comment: @Egor I tried building with -info, -debug, and -stacktrace all produced the same error as shown above and not much more information.

Comment: I have the same problem. Anyone has solved this issue?